# Cast object to id

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an object which inherits from NSObject & I wish to save it in CoreData, I have already create an attribute of type "Transformable" (which is "id"), so I cannot save the project directly when adding it to the database, for example:

```
item.idObject = object;
```

it will generate an error, I think the problem is that I should transform object into id,
how can I do this?

Comment: What eror do you get. Why don't you use subclasses of NSManagedObject?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track by setting the attribute to transformable. But what you also have to to is to write a valueTransformer for this object that Core Data can use.

There is more in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

when you assign a core data property, it may only be of certain types, NSString, NSNumber etc... if you assign a relationship, it must be another NSManagedObject instance, if you want to save it as part of the model, you can of course have transient properties of any type.

so...

```
@implimentation OurClass

@dynamic someProperty; // core data model property NSNumber, NSString, etc.
@dynamic someRelationship; // core data relationship some other subclass of NSManagedObject
@synthesized someOtherProperty; // can be anything, following normal Objective-C semantics.

@end
```

Comment: Transient properties are not persisted to the store.

Comment: @Abizern that is correct, sorry if that was unclear... that was why I called them transient, rather than normal.